# RSelenium: Find link with Xpath

Tags: r, selenium, xpath, rselenium

I want to find all links to PDF files in a page with `RSelenium` and `Xpath`.

Please consider

```
require(RSelenium)
RSelenium::checkForServer()

RSelenium::startServer()

remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html")
```

In the page there are multiple links to PDF files such as

```
<a href="doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf">PDF</a>
```

But my first try

```
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//a[contains(@href,'.pdf')/@href")
```

produces the following error

```
Error:   Summary: InvalidSelector
     Detail: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).
     class: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException
```

Am I getting the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 13):

There is a syntax error inside your expression, missing a closing `]`:

```
//a[contains(@href,'.pdf')]/@href
                      HERE^
```

But, even if you fix it, you'll get an error - a different one this time. This is because XPath expressions in selenium have to point to web elements and not element attributes. In other words, use `//a[contains(@href,'.pdf')]` to find an element and then `get_attribute` method to get the `href` attribute value.

---

Note that you may also find the link *by link text*:

```
remDr$findElement(using = "link text", "PDF")
```